# How to correctly cleaning wordpress options table

Tags: sql, performance

I want to clean my WordPress site options table using SQL.
I'd installed the plugin Performance Lab v2.7.0 by WordPress Performance Team which said that my autoloaded options are making my site slow (indeed that's why I'd installed this plugin in first place).

The culprit of this problems looks like wordpress-https_path_cache with a size of 789.22 KB.

The issue here is that I don't know what to do with this option.

I'd read online that I need it to set it to not as an autoload options but when using myphpadmin to edit this option I received the error:

> "Error in processing request Error code: 413 Error text: Request
> Entity Too Large (rejected) It seems that the connection to server has
> been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status."

I don't know if this a myphpadmin problem it's that I doing something wrong.

There are others options that I want to clean[image]

Comment: Looks like your `wordpress-https_path_cache` is pretty large, what's that for?  Is it an automated plugin that does `https` redirects for mixed content errors?  You'd be better suited to use 'Better Search and Replace' and just change the records once and for all and then get rid of that plugin.  (If that's what it's doing.)

Comment: That's kind the issue here, I don't know what's for, but definitely your search & replace recommendation it's the best path. Thank you very much. Having said that, let me list my plugins so if someone else respond and also because I''ll be on vacations.
Akismet Anti-spam: Spam Protection, Database Backup for WordPress, MWW Scheduled Post Trigger [unactived], Performance Lab, Really Simple SSL, Site Kit by Google, Transients Manager, W3 Total Cache, WPCode Lite [unactived]

Comment: My guess is that it’s a really Simple SSL table.  The plug-in finds insecure paths and then writes redirects in that table.